# Ubuntu screen recorder with changeable camera background

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, video-recording

i have seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PpKMSk9owc):

[image: ngable]

so i think is there any kind of Ubuntu recorder to do this camera background remover at the recording time, in Ubuntu.

As which i think there is none by this effect, it can be done by modifying some current Ubuntu recorder to do this by some live background remover code like [this](https://github.com/jmlb/insight_project):

**[Background Removal in Real-Time Video Chats using TensorflowJS](https://medium.com/@jmlbeaujour/real-time-matting-of-webcam-video-on-the-browser-part-1-2c71a330ed08)**

[image]
So what screen record are best candidate to do it by having some characteristics  like easy connecting to other languages and flexibility to change codes and ...

**Update:**

I have seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YeRsbRE2_g) video, and found the **[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/)** which do it. by this installation :

> Linux Install Directions
>
> Ubuntu Installation
>
> xserver-xorg version 1.18.4 or newer is recommended to avoid potential
>   performance issues with certain features in OBS, such as the
>   fullscreen projector.
>
> FFmpeg is required. If you do not have the FFmpeg installed (if you're
>   not sure, then you probably don't have it), you can get it with the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
> ```
>
> Then you can install OBS with the following commands, make sure you
>   enabled the multiverse repo in Ubuntu's software center (NOTE: On
>   newer versions of ubuntu adding a repository automatically apt
>   updates.):
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install obs-studio
> ```